# Codeigniter How to redirect back to previous page without losing data

Tags: php, codeigniter, url, redirect

here is my items controller, it displays list of items, and view it from items_view.php.

```
class Items extends CI_Controller{

function  __construct(){
    parent::__construct();
    $this->load->model('crud');
}
function index(){
    $data['items'] = $this->crud->read('items');
    $data['header_info'] = $this->crud->header_info('items');
    #$data['single_row'] = $this->crud->read_single('items','ID', 1);
    $this->load->view('items_view', $data);
}

function edit($id){
    $data['single_row'] = $this->crud->read_single('items','ID', $id);
    $this->load->view('items_view', $data);
}

function insert(){
    if($_POST){
        $data = array(
        'Desc' => $_POST['Desc'],
        'Cost' => $_POST['Cost']        
        );
    if($_POST['status']=='update'){
        $this->crud->update('items', $data, 'ID',$_POST['id']);
        echo "Updated...";
    }elseif ($_POST['status']=='new'){
        $last_row = $this->crud->insert('items', $data);
        if($last_row){
            #Data insertion completed.....
            #now ready to get back my items list page.....!
        }   
    }


    }
  }
}
```

in the items_view.php also have form that can user add some more items to the list, so that i would like, when user submit the form the insert method will execute, so how to get back to my previous page without losing data.

Comment: on form submit, are you storing the values in db??

Comment: @Niranjan N Raju yes i stored it, but getting back to previous page is confused...

Comment: in edit page, after edit, you want to go back to same edit page with all entered values??

Comment: at the beginning user will see a list of items extracted from the database, also user will se blank form to add more items, so if user fill that form and say save, the form will execute Items controller->insert method, after insertion completes i need to show user a list of items with new one in the previous page, so do i need to call the index method again.?

Comment: in index you have form as well as table?

Comment: @Niranjan N Raju, Yes Sir.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/92881/discussion-between-niranjan-n-raju-and-saedawke).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In `insert()` take the id if inserted row or updated row Then redirect to `index()` like this

```
redirect("items/index/".$last_row);
```

In `index()`

```
function index($id = ""){
    if($id) { 
        // fetch data from db and pass it to view
    } else {
        // pass empty value to view
    }
    $data['items'] = $this->crud->read('items');
    $data['header_info'] = $this->crud->header_info('items');
    $this->load->view('items_view', $data);


}
```